# Prevent reordering of elements inside ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop, ngfor

I have a small Array of dynamically rendered components. Now I'm displaying them inside a mat-grid-list with Drag and Drop behaviour. Each Component is inside its own Drag and Drop List for Flexbox reasons.

Now when I try to move one Component to a different Place, all Components get shifted.

Im unable to understand how I can prevent this. The desired behaviour is to only switch source Component and Destination Component inside the Array.

html:

```
<mat-grid-list style="height: 90%" cols="3" rowHeight="fit">
            <mat-grid-tile cdkDropList *ngFor="let dashboardModule of dashboardModules; let i = index" [cdkDropListData]="i">
              <div style="margin: 3rem 3rem;" cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="i" (cdkDragEntered)="dragEntered($event)">
                <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="dictionaryService.componentDictionary[dashboardModule.name]; injector: dictionaryService.injectorDictionary[i]"></ng-container>
              </div>
            </mat-grid-tile>
          </mat-grid-list>
```

function which is called when dragging Components:

```
dragEntered(event: CdkDragEnter): void {
    const sourceIndex = event.item.data;
    const destinationIndex = event.container.data;

    moveItemInArray(this.dashboardModules, sourceIndex, destinationIndex);
    this.dictionaryService.initializeInjectorDictionary(this.dashboardModules);
    this.setModulesInLocalStorage();
  }
```

I observed that the shifting happens even before the drag function gets called.
A gif to visualize my problem:

[image: wrong shifting of components]

Comment: What is the moveItemInArray function doing? Is it removing the item in the old index? Probably you will need to insert a placeholder item on that old position to prevent the items from getting shifted. 

If you could add the definition of that moveItemInArray function we could help a little more.

Comment: This is the documentation:

Moves an item one index in an array to another.
Params:
array – Array in which to move the item.
fromIndex – Starting index of the item.
toIndex – Index to which the item should be moved.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. MoveItemInArray was the issue.

I had to implement the desired functionality myself:

```
const tempDashboardModule = this.dashboardModules[destinationIndex];
this.dashboardModules[destinationIndex] = this.dashboardModules[sourceIndex];
this.dashboardModules[sourceIndex] = tempDashboardModule;
```